# Elastic Search, find documents based on part of value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with a field like this:

```
Sender: Bootstrapper.ScheduleJob.Runner
```

When running this query I'm getting results back:

```
GET _search 
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Bootstrapper.ScheduleJob.Runner"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to search for a partial value like this I don't get any results back:

```
GET _search 
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*strapper.Schedule*"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mapping for my index:

```
{
   "logstash-2016.05.01": {
      "mappings": {
         "redis": {
            "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "sender": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I know wildcard queries does not scale very well with a lot of data, but in this case we will have limited amount of data and it will not affect any user experiences since it is used for visualize logs in the ELK stack. Then `Sender` field can contain a lot of different values, therefore the desired wildcard query.

Any ideas or maybe an alternative approach?

EDIT: I'm using a rather old version of Elastic Search 1.6.0. Can it have something to do with this?

EDIT2: This actually gives documents back, but I'm looking for a query on `_all` or a query where you can specify several fields:

```
GET /logstash-2016.05.01/redis/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "sender": "*strapper.Schedule*" 
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT3:

Running this query:

```
GET /logstash-2016.05.01/_search { "query": { "query_string": { "query": "Bootstrapper.ScheduleJob.Runner" } } }
```

Gives:

```
{
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [_search { \"query\": { \"query_string\": { \"query\": \"Bootstrapper.ScheduleJob.Runner\" } } }]]",
   "status": 400
}
```

This one get the same result as above:

```
GET /logstash-2016.05.01/_search { 
    "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*strapper.Schedule*" } } }
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the case with ES 2.3.2. Both queries returns the document.

Comment: Yes it is strange. Maybe there is some settings that is not set correct. or something Any ideas? It's a part of the ELK stack where logstash is pushing log data into Elastic Search.

Comment: Run this `GET /logstash-2016.05.01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Bootstrapper.ScheduleJob.Runner"
    }
  }
}` and post the exact result you are getting. Then run `GET /logstash-2016.05.01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*strapper.Schedule*"
    }
  }
}`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiStefan. Added result in my post above.

Comment: I don't understand. How did you run that?

Comment: I'm running in a Chrome Plugin called `Sense`. So I tried with Curl instead and I'm actually getting results back from both your queries. I guess the plugin is not working as expected.. Thank you for you help even though it was not related to ES. @AndreiStefan